# Can You Run WebpackDevServer In The Cloud?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server

When using a ReactJS application you run it locally with `npm start`.

This ends up calling `react-scripts start`, which uses the WebpackDevServer.

The documentation says that you *shouldn't* use the dev server for production.

The [reasons for not running it in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52772197/why-should-i-not-use-webpack-dev-server-in-production) are mostly security, obfuscation, minification, size etc.

However, is there any technology reason that means you *can't* use it on a server?

i.e. if you ignore all the issues with running the dev server, will it still actually serve the pages and be accessible from a web page?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can run it there - you just have to set it up.

You should not, but you can.